# How to rotate two wire frame cubes on different axis using classes and pyopengl

Tags: python, rotation, cube, pyopengl, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to figure out how to rotate two 3D cubes on different axis.  I can create two cubes, and I can rotate both cubes in the same direction, but when I try and rotate them in different directions it seems like it is just mixing the two rotations to form a new axis of rotation for both cubes. Also I am new to Python and to Object Oriented Programming.
Thanks

Here is my Code.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import time


class cubeClass:
    def __init__(self):

        self.rotation = [0,0,0,0]

        self.verticies =[
            (1, -1, -1),
            (1, 1, -1),
            (-1, 1, -1),
            (-1, -1, -1),
            (1, -1, 1),
            (1, 1, 1),
            (-1, -1, 1),
            (-1, 1, 1)
            ]

        self.edges = (
            (0,1),
            (0,3),
            (0,4),
            (2,1),
            (2,3),
            (2,7),
            (6,3),
            (6,4),
            (6,7),
            (5,1),
            (5,4),
            (5,7)
            )

    def cube(self):

        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        for self.edge in self.edges:
            for self.vertex in self.edge:
                glVertex3fv(self.verticies[self.vertex])
        glEnd()

        glRotatef(self.rotation[0],self.rotation[1],
                  self.rotation[2],self.rotation[3])
        print(self.rotation)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800,600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

    cube1 = cubeClass()
    cube1.rotation= [1,1,0,0]

    cube2 = cubeClass()
    cube2.rotation = [1,0,1,0]

    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        cube1.cube()  
        cube2.cube()

        pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.time.wait(10)
        #time.sleep(.04)

main()
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you! This is exactly the information and use of glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL operations like [`glRotatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) manipulate the top most element of the OpenGL [matrix stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755998/what-is-the-point-of-the-matrix-stack-in-opengl). Use [`glPushMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) and [`glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) to push matrices on and pop matrices from the matrix stack. [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml) specify the current matrix for the matrix operations.
(see [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL))
The matrix which defines the location and orientation of the mesh is the model view matrix.
(see [Transform the modelMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008171/transform-the-modelmatrix/46008573#46008573))

You have to set the rotation separately for each cube and you have to progressively increment the rotation angle. Adapt your code like this:

```
def cube(self):

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glPushMatrix()
    glRotatef(self.rotation[0],self.rotation[1],
              self.rotation[2],self.rotation[3])

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for self.edge in self.edges:
        for self.vertex in self.edge:
            glVertex3fv(self.verticies[self.vertex])
    glEnd()

    print(self.rotation)

    glPopMatrix()
    self.rotation[0] = self.rotation[0] + 1
```